# URL protocol in query parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

I am using oAuth to try and validate myself against Magento for the purposes of a custom integration, however I am encountering some issues with authentication, namely the /oauth/initiate section.

When sending a GET request that contains query parameters to my address with /oauth/initiate?ALL_OAUTH_PARAMS_HERE I am encountering a 403 forbidden error.

Initially I thought it may be due to my server settings, i.e oauth not installed correctly, MAGE auth.php handler having issues with the default user, i.e 'guest' not 'admin' and all sorts of issues that were in the end fruitless.

I have found though that sending my Authorization request as an OAuth Authorization header passing in all of my values works correctly, whilst this is great, it raises the question as to why this does not work with the query parameter method.

Now after some trial and error and hours of research I have found that when I am sending any query parameters via GET request that contain a url with a protocol I am receiving a 403 forbidden.

As an example this would result in a 403:

GET https://www.mysite.com/oAuth/initiate?callback_url=http://www.example.com
GET https://www.mysite.com/oAuth/initiate?callback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com

Yet this would not

GET https://www.mysite.com/oAuth/initiate?callback_url=www.example.com

I am lead to believe, as my environment is on a shared hosting platform, using cPanel and Apache, that it is a mod_security issue that is preventing protocols from being passed in query strings.

Is there anything that may be causing this behaviour within the HTACCESS file that I could change to prevent this behaviour, or do we all believe that this is only something a hosting provider may change. I have looked at my HTACCESS and foudn nothing glaringly obvious to cause this behaviour so am at a loss.

Also, what are the implications or security issues concerning having protocols within query parameters, I cannot see why this rule would be invented, but I may be being short sighted.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* disable mod_security, you can do:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

But this is assuming your hosting provider has compiled mod_security to allow htaccess override.